# C# UWP и веб-сервис

Tags: c#, uwp, веб-служба

Есть просто приложение на C# UWP, в котором по нажатию на кнопку происходит определенное событие (включается реле на плате).
Подскажите, можно ли в это приложение как-то добавить веб-сервис, чтобы я мог управлять этой кнопкой через браузер?
Есть у кого примеры чего-то похожего? Весь интернет перерыл не могу найти.

Comment: Вам нужен вебсайт? Или вебсервис? Или у вас уже есть что то, что вы хотите только интегрировать в свое приложение?

Comment: Веб-сервис. Допустим запускаю приложение, на другом ПК открываю браузер, вбиваю адрес для подключения к веб-сервису, и уже в браузере нажимаю кнопку (Включить реле) - оно включается на плате.
Примерно как управление умным домом или например роботом-пылесосом.

Comment: UWP для таких целей... Какой то не правильный подход. UWP хорош для клиента, но не для сервера. Создали бы лучше сервер, который реализовывал интерфейс взаимодействия с платой и на UWP/Web сделали бы клиент приложение, которое подключалось бы к этому серверу. А так, не какой стабильности, нечего толком вы не получите. Win10 даже фоновые UWP ограничивает, тот же простейший Torrent клиент криво работает в фоне, чего уж говорить о поднятие Web-сервиса...

Comment: А вот любопытно мнение, для какой ниши приложений подходит UWP? Калькулятор и тетрис? Там же толком все ограниченно, чего не коснись.

Comment: веб сервисы предназначены для взаимодействия программы с программой, у них нет интерфейса с кнопками. Интерфейс с кнопками - для взамодействия человек-программа, можно реализовать как веб сайт. Это вам просто ключевые слова, куда смотреть, так как если вы ищете как спроектировть веб сервис, то, скорее всего, найдете не то, что вам надо.

Comment: @NewView Почти для любой. Игры, клиентские приложения, банковские и много чего другого. Я например часто использую приложения для просмотра новостей, видеоплеер у меня UWP, просмотр почты, фото - тоже UWP, Skype в конце концов тоже уже не чем не хуже десктоп версии. Я считаю, что за UWP будущее. Но сервер на них запускать, это конечно странная затея.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение, но есть впечатление, что с учётом что Win10Mobile прекратила свое существование, "много платформенность" UWP приложений теперь вызывает сомнения.

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь, понял в какую сторону нужно смотреть

Comment: @NewView Чтоб не разводить дискуссию, оставлю последний комментарий. Вы не в ту сторону смотрите, UWP это не кроссплатформенность (хотя и поддерживает), это замена всем Win32 приложения Windows, ибо их уже давно приняли за не безопасные и тормозящие прогресс и Microsoft намерены полностью от них отказаться! Разрабатывается такая вещь, как WCOS, это OS Windows, которая переписана с нуля, в ней нету поддержки Win32 приложений, в ней весь интерфейс, все приложения на UWP технологии. Она должна быть ядром для всех будущих OS, которое будет расширятся модулями. Вот тогда и будет явная польза.